# Need to check if processing instruction `<?covid19?>` is present in XML or not

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xml, processing-instruction

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Journal Publishing DTD v1.1d1 20130915//EN" "JATS-journalpublishing1.dtd"[]>
<article dtd-version="1.1d1" article-type="review-article" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xml:lang="en">
<front>
<?covid19?>
```

I need to find if the `<?covid19?>` processing instruction is present in the XML or not.

Pseudo-code in jQuery:

```js
$("<?covid19?>").length
```

Comment: jQuery is ill-equipped to find XML processing instructions, so I’m not sure why you want jQuery here. You can use the [`TreeWalker` API](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) to find this processing instruction.

Comment: I’ve reopened this post. The previous [duplicate target](/q/13032046/4642212) was specific to the XMLDOM library for Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

While there are no CSS selectors to select processing instructions like elements, there are two nice APIs which you can use to avoid iterating over the DOM tree manually.

Let’s say your XML document is the [`XMLDocument`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLDocument) `theDocument`; you can create one by [parsing the XML string](/q/7949752/4642212) with the [`DOMParser` API](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMParser):

```js
const xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <?covid19 content-a?>
  <?covid19 content-b?>
  <?thing x?>
  <child>
    <?covid19 content-c?>
    <?thing y?>
  </child>
  <covid19>
    Reject this node.
  </covid19>
</root>`,
  theDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
```

### `NodeIterator` API

Finding all processing instructions is possible using the [`NodeIterator` API](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator) (using [`theDocument.createNodeIterator`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/createNodeIterator)).

```js
const iteratorAll = theDocument
    .createNodeIterator(theDocument, NodeFilter.SHOW_PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION);

const iteratorCOVID19 = theDocument
    .createNodeIterator(theDocument, NodeFilter.SHOW_PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION, {
      acceptNode(node){
        if(node.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "covid19"){
          return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
        }

        return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
      }
    });
```

`iteratorAll` is a `NodeIterator` which shows all processing instructions.
`iteratorCOVID19` is a `NodeIterator` which shows all processing instructions with the name `covid19`.

The [`TreeWalker` API](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) (using [`theDocument.createTreeWalker`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker)) is very similar to the `NodeIterator` API.

### XPath Iterator API

Finding all processing instructions is also possible using [XPath](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/XPath) (using [`theDocument.evaluate`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate)).
The results are [`XPathResult`s](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XPathResult).

```js
const xPathAll = theDocument
    .evaluate("//processing-instruction()", theDocument, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE);

const xPathCOVID19 = theDocument
    .evaluate("//processing-instruction('covid19')", theDocument, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE);
```

Explanation of the [XPath syntax](//www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev):

| Token | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `//` | Get all descendants |
| `processing-instruction()` | Get nodes of type “processing instruction” |
| `processing-instruction('covid19')` | Get nodes of type “processing instruction” with the node name `covid19` |

The [`XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XPathResult/resultType) is useful to ensure that the nodes get returned in document-order.

`xPathAll` is an `XPathResult` iterator which shows all processing instructions.
`xPathCOVID19` is an `XPathResult` iterator which shows all processing instructions with the name `covid19`.

### Iteration helper

The two APIs are great in terms of browser support, but that means they’re old enough that they don’t have a modern [iteration protocol](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator).
But this is where a [generator](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) proves useful.

This code defines the generator function `consumeDOMIterator` which will just fully consume all nodes found by either iterator.
Since the `NodeIterator` API’s method to get the next result is called [`nextNode`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator/nextNode), and the XPath method is called [`iterateNext`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XPathResult/iterateNext), this function checks which of these method names to use.
If it can’t find the appropriate method, it’ll [defer](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) to the default iteration protocol.
Then, a simple `while` loop repeatedly calls one of these methods and [`yield`s](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) them until `null` is returned.

```js
function* consumeDOMIterator(iterator){
  const method = (iterator instanceof NodeIterator || iterator instanceof TreeWalker
    ? "nextNode"
    : iterator instanceof XPathResult && [
      XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE,
      XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE
    ].includes(iterator.resultType)
    ? "iterateNext"
    : null);
  
  if(!method){
    yield* iterator[Symbol.iterator]();
    
    return;
  }
  
  let node;
  
  while((node = iterator[method]())){
    yield node;
  }
}
```

Now the function can be used to create an Array from the iterator.
[`Array.from`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) can be used to achieve this easily:

```js
Array.from(consumeDOMIterator(iteratorCOVID19))

// Or any of these:
Array.from(consumeDOMIterator(xPathCOVID19))
Array.from(consumeDOMIterator(iteratorAll))
Array.from(consumeDOMIterator(xPathAll))
```

To check the existence of a processing instruction, simply check the Array’s `length` or if `iteratorCOVID19.nextNode()` or `xPathCOVID19.iterateNext()` return a `Node`.

Note that its name includes `consume` for a reason: once you start iterating over the API results using this function to create an Array, the state of the results changes.
Once you reach the end, either iterator will be at the “end” of the document, so there is no next node.
While the `NodeIterator` API has a [`previousNode`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator/previousNode), the XPath Iterator API does not have a corresponding method; *in general* iterators can only be iterated once.

### XPath Snapshot API

Alternatively, `XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE` may be used to get a more direct set of results that can be iterated over more easily.

```js
const snapshotAll = theDocument
    .evaluate("//processing-instruction()", theDocument, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE);

const snapshotCOVID19 = theDocument
    .evaluate("//processing-instruction('covid19')", theDocument, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE);
```

Now, since the `XPathResult` is a snapshot, the [`snapshotLength`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XPathResult/snapshotLength) can be used in order to get all the [`snapshotItem`s](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XPathResult/snapshotItem).
Again, `Array.from` can be used to achieve this easily:

```js
Array.from({
  length: snapshotCOVID19.snapshotLength
}, (_, index) => snapshotCOVID19.snapshotItem(index));
```

The only difference to the iterator approach is that the `XPathResult` does not change when the underlying document is mutated.

To check the existence of a processing instruction, simply check the Array’s `length` or if `snapshotCOVID19.snapshotItem(0)` returns a `Node`.

### Full code

This code snippet demonstrates in full how to get all processing instructions of the form `<?covid19?>` and, for example, get their `nodeValue`:

```js
function* consumeDOMIterator(iterator){
  const method = (iterator instanceof NodeIterator || iterator instanceof TreeWalker
    ? "nextNode"
    : iterator instanceof XPathResult && [
      XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE,
      XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE
    ].includes(iterator.resultType)
    ? "iterateNext"
    : null);
  
  if(!method){
    yield* iterator[Symbol.iterator]();
    
    return;
  }
  
  let node;
  
  while((node = iterator[method]())){
    yield node;
  }
}

const xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <?covid19 content-a?>
  <?covid19 content-b?>
  <?thing x?>
  <child>
    <?covid19 content-c?>
    <?thing y?>
  </child>
  <covid19>
    Reject this node.
  </covid19>
</root>`,
  theDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "text/xml"),
  iteratorAll = theDocument
    .createNodeIterator(theDocument, NodeFilter.SHOW_PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION),
  iteratorCOVID19 = theDocument
    .createNodeIterator(theDocument, NodeFilter.SHOW_PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION, {
      acceptNode(node){
        if(node.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "covid19"){
          return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
        }

        return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
      }
    }),
  xPathAll = theDocument
    .evaluate("//processing-instruction()", theDocument, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE),
  xPathCOVID19 = theDocument
    .evaluate("//processing-instruction('covid19')", theDocument, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE),
  snapshotAll = theDocument
    .evaluate("//processing-instruction()", theDocument, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE),
  snapshotCOVID19 = theDocument
    .evaluate("//processing-instruction('covid19')", theDocument, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE);

const demoIterator = (iterator) => Array.from(consumeDOMIterator(iterator), ({ nodeName, nodeValue }) => [
  nodeName,
  nodeValue
]);
const demoIterator2 = (iterator) => Array.from(consumeDOMIterator(iterator), ({ nodeValue }) => nodeValue);

console.log("All PIs using NodeIterator", demoIterator(iteratorAll));
console.log("All PIs using XPath Iterator", demoIterator(xPathAll));
console.log("All PIs using XPath Snapshot", Array.from({
  length: snapshotAll.snapshotLength
}, (_, index) => {
  const {
      nodeName,
      nodeValue
    } = snapshotAll.snapshotItem(index);
  
  return [
    nodeName,
    nodeValue
  ];
}));

console.log("All node values of <?covid19?> PIs using NodeIterator", demoIterator2(iteratorCOVID19));
console.log("All node values of <?covid19?> PIs using XPath Iterator", demoIterator2(xPathCOVID19));
console.log("All node values of <?covid19?> PIs using XPath Snapshot", Array.from({
  length: snapshotCOVID19.snapshotLength
}, (_, index) => snapshotCOVID19.snapshotItem(index).nodeValue));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```